# Extract date from UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uidatepicker

Can u please tell me how to extract a date from UIDatePicker, i have extracted the month but i am not able to extract the date,Please help me out

Thank You

Answer (score 6):

The `NSDate` object can be extracted by just accessing the `date` property of the object:

```
NSDate *dateFromPicker = [someDatePicker date];
```

If you want to extract detailed information about what month, day and year a person has chosen, this is a little bit more complex (but just a little bit). The solution is to use an NSCalendar reference - it is likely that you'd want to use Gregorian.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
```

Now you should use an unsigned integer unit flags to specify which units you want to extract from a date (i.e. day, day-of-the-month, year, era etc.). Use a bitwise | to select multiple unit flags:

```
unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit;
```

Now create a date components object:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components: unitFlags fromDate: dateFromPicker];
```

From this components date, you can now extract integer values of what you have mentioned in the unitFlags integer:

```
int year = [components year];
int month = [components month];
```

All other properties (i.e. day, day-of-the-month, era etc.) are undefined in such a components object - remember, you can only extract what you've explicitly said you want to extract.

Finally, free the calendar object to avoid memory leaks:

```
[calendar release];
```

Hope this helps.
For more information, see Apple reference: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `date` property of the `UIDatePicker` class to get the date!