# How to get a date and time from a UIDatePicker and notify the user when that date has arrived?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uidatepicker

I need to get a date and time from a UIDatePicker and fire a local notification when that date and time has arrived. How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Register for Local Notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529590/register-for-local-notification) - that question even pulls the date from a date picker, as does [Extract date from UIDatePicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172079/extract-date-from-uidatepicker?rq=1)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277334/schedulelocalnotification-doesnt-work/12277465#12277465

Answer (score 3):

use this code

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    // Get the current date
    NSDate *pickerDate = your date from date picker;

    // Break the date up into components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];
    // Set up the fire time
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
    [dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
    [dateComps release];


    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;

    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        // Notification details
        localNotif.alertBody = @"Write your text here";
    // Set the action button
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;


    // Specify custom data for the notification
    NSStream *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cId];
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:str forKey:@"NotificationDate"];
    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];


    NSLog(@"The notifications are:%@",[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications]);
    NSLog(@"The %@",localNotif.userInfo);

    [localNotif release];
```

Comment: Thanks! So this will get a date from a date picker in my view, then fire a notification when that date and time has arrived?

Comment: Yes you are right !!!

Comment: Pradip I have this code in my app, however how would I go about changing the format to display mm/dd/yyyy and a 12 hour clock?  Here is a link to my code and question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174337/uidatepicker-displays-2013-04-23-161210-instead-of-1110

Answer (score 1):

Use `self.datePicker.date` to store the target date with time.

Then make a NSTimer that will poll every miilisecond to check if current date equals to target date. As both become equal then show the alertview.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but could you give me a code example? I'm not familiar with this part of Objective-C.